# Как автоматически создать страницы wordress в определенном блоге мультисайта?

Tags: wordpress

Автоматически создаю блог для каждого пользователя

```
$new_blog = wpmu_create_blog($domain, $path, $title, $user_id);
if( is_wp_error( $new_blog ) ){
     echo  $new_blog->get_error_message();
} else {
    //there want add pages
}
```

Как в этом блоге создать страницы? Ведь стандартный код добавляет на текущий "блог"(

```
$page_data = array(
                    'post_type'     => 'page',
                    'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( 'About us' ),
                    'post_content'  => '',
                    'post_status'   => 'publish',
                    'post_author'   => $user_id,
);
$page_id = wp_insert_post( $post_data );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед созданием страницы переключитесь на нужный блог:

```
switch_to_blog( $new_blog );
```

После создания с помощью `wp_insert_post()` вернитесь в текущий блог:

```
restore_current_blog();
```